# python2.7 os.system output weird result

Tags: python

I am trying to execute an `.exe` file in Python, but the result are weird:

```
>>>python
>>>import os

//this one works well
>>>os.system("dopt.exe ks_4_0")

//this one pop out a lot of 1
>>>os.system("dopt.exe ./data/ks_4_0")
```

I tried `".//data//ks_4_0"`, `".\\data\\ks_4_0"`, `".\data\ks_4_0"`, `"data/ks_4_0"` and so on.

All of them keep popping out a lot of `"1"`s.
What is going wrong?

Comment: `ks_4_0` and `./data/ks_4_0` are different files. That's probably the reason. Without knowing what `dopt.exe` is, it's hard to say more.

Comment: When you have slashes, it is a good idea to use raw strings, to prevent Python from escaping characters. Like this: os.system(r"dopt.exe ./data/ks_4_0")

Comment: Thanks, user2357112, I find out error, the hardcoded path of my exe cause the problem